# Local WP connection with MAMP broken

Tags: wordpress, macos, mamp, macos-sierra

Sorry for a perhaps very basic question, but here it goes:

I’ve developed a WP site locally on my Mac, with help from MAMP. Haven’t touched the site in a couple of months, and now I can’t connect. Simply get the “can’t establish connection to server” message in Safari.

I’ve tried to search for a solution, but found it hard. Is there an easy fix? I might have updated my system from Sierra to High Sierra since I last worked on the WP site, could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: It could be cause by the update

Comment: Really slim chance of fixing it but try changing the ports that mamp uses, I use 80, 81, 443 etc. Update MAMP to latest version too, though I've not had any issues at all

Comment: That did it, @AndyHolmes! Thank you!!!

Comment: I've popped an answer for you if you wouldn't mind accepting :)

Comment: Hey @GustavSvedung, any chance you can accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, your ports may be an issue since you have updated - make sure you also update MAMP to the latest version.

Once you have updated MAMP, try to use ports `80, 81, 443` etc. this should hopefully fix your issue.